# When is a hash table better to use than a search tree?

Tags: c++

When is a hash table better to use than a search tree?

Comment: What is a search tree? If you mean an ordered collection, then the answer is just that: when you don't need ordering you can use a hash table.

Comment: Search trees aren't ordered. They're sorted if you traverse them in postfix or prefix order, but they're not ordered.

Comment: @Daniel, from Wikipedia: "In computer science, a search tree is a tree data structure in whose nodes data values can be stored from some ordered set, which is such that in an in-order traversal of the tree the nodes are visited in ascending order of the stored values." A Binary search tree and a B-Tree are two examples of search trees.

Answer (score 9):

Depends on what you want to do with the data structure.

```
Operation         Hash table  Search Tree
Search            O(1)        O(log(N))
Insert            O(1)        O(log(N))
Delete            O(1)        O(log(N))
Traversal         O(N)        O(N)
Min/Max-Key       -hard-      O(log(N))
Find-Next-Key     -hard-      O(1)
```

- Insert, Search on Hashtable depend on the load factor of the hash 
  table and its design. Poorly designed hastables can have O(N) search and insert. The same is true for your Search Tree.
- Deleting in a hash table can be cumbersome depending on your collision
  resolution stategy.
- Traversing the container, Finding Min/Max, Find Next/Prev sort of
  operations are better on a search tree because of its ordering.
- All estimates of search tree above are for 'balanced' search trees.

Comment: I'd like to see a hash table with O(1) access. My eyes bleed already from seeing these misnomers.

Comment: A properly designed hash table *does* have O(1) lookup, despite collision resolution.  This is because lookup time is constant - it doesn't matter how large the table gets.  For example, (in theory) a hash table with 1000 elements will have the same worst-case lookup time as a hash table with 1,000,000,000 elements.  Whereas a tree with 1000 elements has worst-case `log2(1,000) = 10` accesses, but a tree with a billion elements has worst-case `log2(1,000,000,000) = 30` accesses.

Comment: @Charles: assuming properties of the hash function that may or may not actually materialize - namely that it's O(1) and uniform. That said, those figures for the tree are expressed in terms of the number of comparisons made, not in terms of running time, so it's all in the fine print.

Comment: Traversing a hash table in a random order can be made efficient (see for example LinkedHashMap). If you want to traverse it in increasing order than a tree is better.

Answer (score 1):

When the average access and insertion time are more important than the best access and insertion time. Practically I think search trees are usually as good a solution as hash tables, because even though in theory big theta of one is better than big theta of log n, log n is very fast, and as you start dealing with large values of n the effect on the practical difference shrinks. Also, big theta of one says nothing about the value of the constant. Granted, this holds for the complexity of trees as well, but the constant factors of trees are much more fixed, usually at a very low number, among implementations than those of hash tables.

Again, I know theorists will disagree with me here, but it's computers we're dealing with here, and for log n to be of any significance burden for a computer n must be unrealistically large. If n is a trillion then log of n is 40, and a computer today can perform 40 iterations rather quickly. For log of n to grow to 50 you already have over a quadrillion elements.

The C++ standard as it stands today doesn't provide a hash-table among its containers and I think there's a reason people were fine with it as it is for over a decade.

Comment: "there's a reason people were fine with it as it is for over a decade" - reason might be that both the STL and TR1 include a hash table, so something has always been quite widely available. If the key is a string, for example, then it's quite plausible for a hashing function to be faster than (say) 20 string comparisons, especially if a lot of the strings have a significant common prefix. If you're only going to look up 1 key, ever, then you're quite right that it's all fast. But if lookups is basically all your program does, sometimes a factor of just 2 would matter a lot.

Comment: The only reason the first C++ standard did not include hash tables is because they wanted to ship the damn thing already.

Answer (score 1):

My take on things:

```
Operation                  Hash table(1)  SBB Search Tree(2)
.find(obj) -> obj          O(1)           O(1)*

.insert(obj)               O(1)           O(log(N))

.delete(obj)               O(1)           O(log(N))

.traverse / for x in...    O(N)           O(N)

.largerThan(obj) -> {objs} unsupported    O(log(N))
                                           \
                                            union right O(1) + parent O(1)

.sorted() -> [obj]         unsupported    no need
                                           \
                                            already sorted so no need
                                            to print out, .traverse() is O(N)

.findMin() -> obj          unsupported**  O(log(N)), maybe O(1)
                                           \
                                            descend from root, e.g.:
                                            root.left.left.left...left -> O(log(N))
                                            might be able to cache for O(1)

.findNext(obj) -> obj      unsupported    O(log(N))
                                           \
                                            first perform x=.find(obj) which is O(1)
                                            then descend from that node, e.g.:
                                            x.right.left.left...right -> O(log(N))
```

(1) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

(2) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree , e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tango_tree or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splay_tree

(*) You can use a hash table in conjunction with a search tree to obtain this. There is no asymptotic speed or space penalty. Otherwise, it's `O(log(N))`.

(**) Unless you never delete, in which case just cache smallest and largest elements and it's `O(1)`.

These costs may be amortized.

**Conclusion:**

**You want to use trees when the ordering matters.**

Answer (score 0):

Among many issues, it depends on how expensive the hash function is. In my experience, hashes are generally about twice as fast as balanced trees for a sensible hash function, but it's certainly possible for them to be slower.